# Master page elements displaying when no master applied

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

this is driving me mad and I'm hoping one of you will have a solution for this.
I have a master page spread here containing 2 pictures and 2 red lines.
[image]
***Just to clarify this is not one red line going across from one page to another.** The left page has one red line that ends at the centre line and the right page has one red line that begins at the centre line.* 
[image]

I have applied this master to all the pages apart from one as you can see in the picture below:
[image]

However, the line that's on the right master page spread still gets applied to the page  and I don't know why this is happening. Could someone please let me know how to stop this from happening in the future? I made sure to select the right master page before I created the red line on the right, so why is it applying itself even though I didn't apply a master page to this specific page?
[image]

I hope this makes sense, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Check the end caps of the lines, if it is different than the first option, the line will remain at both pages.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The *slightest* overlap of items on one side of spread will cause them to also fall on the other side of the spread, often taking precedence.

It appears to me that you have some overlap on the master page spread.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the master pages as single pages. Break the red line into 2 objects, one for each half of the master page. Make sure they start and end exactly at the edge of each master page.

Comment: They are two objects. That's why it's so confusing. The spread contains of 2 pictures and 2 lines. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Double check. I just tried the same situation in my InDesign and yes, this only happens if the red line is a single object. My source file here https://we.tl/secKRKchNR Force apply the None master to any page and see what happens?

Comment: Even if you do have 2 objects there, make sure the line on the left page does NOT extend on the right master page.

Comment: Also likely you may have had that page with the A master applied initially, in which case the object might be a leftover if you made an over-ride, unlocking it from the applied master.

Comment: I did have it applied initially, if this is a leftover, how do I get rid of it? And why do I only have part of the master as a leftover?

Comment: Go to that page and try to select the object. If that doesn't work CTRL+click it or press CTRL+ALT+L to unlock it in case it is locked. Then delete.

Comment: I'm unable to select the item on the page, also moving the lines far away from the middle also didn't seem to help either.